# Slick compare table column with null

Tags: scala, slick

Can someone please tell me how do we compare a table column against NULL using slick's lifted embedding.

What i want to achieve in mysql:

```
select * from Users where email = '<some_email_addr>' and ( removed = NULL OR removed <= 1 )
```

It gives me an errors at x.removed === null when i try:

```
val q = for {
    x <- Users
        if x.email === email && ( x.removed === null || x.removed <= 1 )
} yield x.removed
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
x.removed.isNull
```

I think that is what you are looking for

Comment: `isNull` and `isNotNull` have been deprecated and replaced by `isEmpty` and `isDefined`. Source: [slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0-RC2/upgrade.html)

Answer (score 7):

As daaatz said and per http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html#isnull-and-isnotnull you should use `isEmpty`, but it only works on Option columns. A workaround is `x.removed.?.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
x.removed.isEmpty()
```

There are no nulls in scala ;-)

Comment: Thanks..but I tried that and now getting:
value isEmpty is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Int]]

Comment: .isNull is the correct answer -- there may not be nulls in scala but there certainly are in SQL! I must admit though, I wanted to use the normal Option[] methods as well. Would be great if Slick added .isEmpty / .isDefined to make it more Scala-like.

Comment: There certainly are nulls allowed in Scala. They're just almost always a bad idea and almost never used.